# Grok and mutate in Logstash filter gives no effect to the output

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Logstash will gather the information via Filebeat on the remote host.
my final expected result is create a graph for showing response time from HTTP log day by day.
So I'm focusing on **response time** in the log message.

Now the json message got from the Kibana looks like this

```
{
  "_index": "filebeat-7.9.2-2020.10.06-000001",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "NYaZB3UB-JR2hYtrwawX",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2020-10-08T09:45:17.358Z",
    "agent": {
      "id": "acbc8cf5-7bc1-46ab-a9ad-8ee1fef26183",
      "name": "42dcb5cf4d4a",
      "type": "filebeat",
      "version": "7.9.2",
      "hostname": "42dcb5cf4d4a",
      "ephemeral_id": "e45f89ee-f355-4490-b79b-394a2226ffe7"
    },
    "log": {
      "offset": 5157015,
      "file": {
        "path": "/usr/logs/tomcat/test.com.access.2020-10-08.log"
      }
    },
    "message": "203.149.37.226 - - [08/Oct/2020:11:45:10 +0200] \"POST /TestserviceWarning/get_warning/render?method=get_warnings_onsite_status_excel&subDomain=testClick&webId=1196&scanId=4482 HTTP/1.1\" 200 1151 0.010",
    "tags": [
      "tomcat"
    ],
    "input": {
      "type": "log"
    },
    "ecs": {
      "version": "1.5.0"
    },
    "host": {
      "name": "42dcb5cf4d4a"
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2020-10-08T09:45:17.358Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1602150317358
  ]
}
```

and my pipeline configuration

```
input {
        beats {
                port => 5000
        }
}

filter {
        if "tomcat" in [tags] {
                grok {
                        match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:client} %{DATA} %{DATA:user} \[%{DATA:logtimestamp} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:timezone}\] \"%{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:uri_path}(%{URIPARAM:params}|) %{DATA:protocol}\" %{NUMBER:code} (%{NUMBER:bytes}|%{DATA}) %{NUMBER:response_time_sec}"}
                        overwrite => [ "message" ]
                }
                mutate { add_field => {"respones_time" => "%{response_time_sec}"}
                }
        }
}
```

Once the pipeline is triggers, I didn't see any additional field in my json message. The result remain the same.

---

Edited on 9/10/2020

after waisted the time for a whole day, I still unable to make it work.

So I turned on the DEBUG log level, it seems like the Logstash is able to access the filter but its somehow doesn't apply the filter to the output.

````
 org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.ComputeStepSyntaxElement@8d7da797
 P[filter-grok{"match"=>{"message"=>"%{IPORHOST:client} %{DATA} %{DATA:user} \\[%{DATA:logtimestamp} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:timezone}\\] \\\"%{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:uri_path}(%{URIPARAM:params}|) %{DATA:protocol}\\\" %{NUMBER:code} (%{NUMBER:bytes}|%{DATA}) %{NUMBER:response_time_sec}"}}|[file]/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf:9:17:```
grok {
                        match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:client} %{DATA} %{DATA:user} \[%{DATA:logtimestamp} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:timezone}\] \"%{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:uri_path}(%{URIPARAM:params}|) %{DATA:protocol}\" %{NUMBER:code} (%{NUMBER:bytes}|%{DATA}) %{NUMBER:response_time_sec}"}
                     }
```] 
 into 
 org.logstash.config.ir.compiler.ComputeStepSyntaxElement@8d7da797
````

Then I've seen new abnormal messages

```
[INFO ] 2020-10-09 06:24:55.568 [Agent thread] agent - Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[INFO ] 2020-10-09 06:24:55.649 [Api Webserver] agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
```

and

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$6 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @72da5f0e
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logstash configuration looks correct. Below is the output from logstash and the same should be ingested in Elastic search. I am assuming you have re-ingested the log file after putting in the latest configuration. Also, made sure that logstash configuration is reloaded and also refreshed the index in Kibana so it identifies the latest fields.

```
{
    "response_time_sec" => "0.010",
             "timezone" => "+0200",
           "@timestamp" => 2020-10-08T13:10:21.115Z,
                 "host" => "4ddee8887e1b",
               "client" => "203.149.37.226",
        "respones_time" => "0.010",
             "@version" => "1",
                "bytes" => "1151",
                 "path" => "/usr/share/logstash/stack/data/data.log",
         "logtimestamp" => "08/Oct/2020:11:45:10",
               "method" => "POST",
             "uri_path" => "/TestserviceWarning/get_warning/render",
                 "user" => "-",
             "protocol" => "HTTP/1.1",
                 "code" => "200",
               "params" => "?method=get_warnings_onsite_status_excel&subDomain=testClick&webId=1196&scanId=4482",
              "message" => "203.149.37.226 - - [08/Oct/2020:11:45:10 +0200] \"POST /TestserviceWarning/get_warning/render?method=get_warnings_onsite_status_excel&subDomain=testClick&webId=1196&scanId=4482 HTTP/1.1\" 200 1151 0.010"
}
```

Although what you want to achieve can be simply done by below

```
filter {
   grok{
     match =>  { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:client} %{DATA} %{DATA:user} \[%{DATA:logtimestamp} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:timezone}\] \"%{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:uri_path}(%{URIPARAM:params}|) %{DATA:protocol}\" %{NUMBER:code} (%{NUMBER:bytes}|%{DATA}) %{NUMBER:response_time}"} 
   }
}
```

The output fields would like

```
{
                "bytes" => "1151",
             "@version" => "1",
         "logtimestamp" => "08/Oct/2020:11:45:10",
               "method" => "POST",
                 "code" => "200",
               "client" => "203.149.37.226",
                 "host" => "169f8e2acdce",
             "timezone" => "+0200",
               "params" => "?method=get_warnings_onsite_status_excel&subDomain=testClick&webId=1196&scanId=4482",
                 "path" => "/usr/share/logstash/stack/data/data.log",
           "@timestamp" => 2020-10-08T13:15:31.576Z,
             "uri_path" => "/TestserviceWarning/get_warning/render",
                 "user" => "-",
             "protocol" => "HTTP/1.1",
    "response_time_sec" => "0.010",
              "message" => "203.149.37.226 - - [08/Oct/2020:11:45:10 +0200] \"POST /TestserviceWarning/get_warning/render?method=get_warnings_onsite_status_excel&subDomain=testClick&webId=1196&scanId=4482 HTTP/1.1\" 200 1151 0.010"
}
```

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, the actual code using the correct syntax

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I'm edited the post for adding more details

Comment: Can you output to stdout and share that maybe it will help me understand it more. Also do the same without filter as well, sometimes it helps understand what input your are getting from Beats.  ```output {
    stdout {}
}```

Comment: The issue was fixed!, definitely my misunderstood about Logstash docker run command, I fixed the output to ES and neglected Logstash.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help.